# Type casting from char* to int*

Tags: c, pointers, types, casting, typecasting-operator

I am learning c in school , and having a little confusion on how to use type casting.
here is my code.

I am trying to figure out what type casting is and how it works.

I initialized a pointer(ptr3) that points the adress of k, then initialized ptr4 and assign ptr3 that is converted into int*.

but this does not seem like working, since it gives random values every time.

Why is it?

I appreciate any feedback ! thank you so much.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() { 
 
  char k = 10;
  
  char* ptr3 = &k;

  int* ptr4 = (int*) ptr3; 
  
  printf("*ptr3  = %d *ptr4  = %d\n", *ptr3, *ptr4); 
  

  return 0;
}
```

output is

```
*ptr3  = 10 *ptr4  = 1669824522
```

Comment: It's undefined behavior.  Why do *you* think it ought to work?  Can you justify your claim based on references or other reliable sources about the C language?

Comment: Surely you didn't learn this. You are telling the compiler to make instructions that interpret the memory that is used to store `k` and whatever 3 bytes come after it (undefined) as an integer. What kind of output did you expect?

Comment: The best thing to learn about casting is to not do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two undefined behaviour in one line.

1. When you dereference `int *` pointer you read outside the `k` object which is illegal.
2. Even if the `k` had enough size (for example is a char array), using the data as another type violates the strict aliasing rules - which is UB as well

Generally speaking, do not typecast pointers unless you really know what you are doing. If you want to convert byte array to integer use `memcpy` functionh.

Answer (score 1):

A `char` is 1 byte in size, however, an integer is 4 bytes.

What you are doing is called Type Punning, where you are telling the compiler to not convert your `char` to an `int` and directly read 4 bytes from that same memory address while you are only allocating 1 byte. Those other 3 bytes could be anything.

The bytes of the char look like this:

```
10
```

Real simple, only one number. Integers need 3 more bytes than a char so here is what the integer could look like in bytes:

```
10 ? ? ?
```

The solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{ 
    char k = 10;
    int i = (int)k;

    printf("k = %d  i = %d\n", k, i); 

    return 0;
}
```

This code instead of directly reading the memory tells the compiler to convert the `char` to an `int`, filling in those 3 random bytes in the process with zeros. Here is what the variable `i` could look like in memory:

```
10 0 0 0
```

Those last 3 bytes were filled in with zeros and the integer is 10.

I hope this answer helps and I am open to feedback to improve it.